# Make query with sub queries faster

Tags: mysql

I have the mysql query below which select rows from a parent table and gets a count and sum of a child table. Is there a way to increase performance?

```
select
    parent.id,
    parent.date,
    parent.name,
    (select count(child.id) 
     from child 
     where child.parentid = parent.id) as count,
    (select sum(child.amount) 
     from child 
     where child.parentid = parent.id) as sum
from 
    parent
```

Comment: I have removed unrelated tags, re-tag again which you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `JOIN` is a efficient method:

```
select p.id, p.date, p.name, c.count, c.sum
from parent p left join (
        select parentid , count(*) as count, sum(amount) as sum
        from child
        group by parentid 
       ) c on c.parentid = p.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `OUTER APPLY/LATERAL JOIN` to avoid duplicating subquery:

```
select
  parent.id,
  parent.date,
  parent.name,
  sub.cnt,
  sub.total
from parent
OUTER APPLY (select count(child.id) AS cnt, sum(child.amount) AS total
             from child where child.parentid = parent.id) sub
```

---

Just saw MySQL tag:

```
SELECT parent.id,
  parent.date,
  parent.name,
  count(child.id) AS cnt,
  sum(child.amount) AS total
FROM parent
LEFT JOIN child 
  ON child.parentid = parent.id
GROUP BY parent.id, parent.date, parent.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it comes down to trying variations the query and evaluating the execution plan, but it may be faster to do a left join and then group if the current query plan is doing a lookup for every parent record.

```
SELECT p.id, p.[date], p.name, COUNT(c.id) AS childCount, SUM(c.amount) AS childSum
FROM parent AS p
LEFT JOIN child AS c ON c.parentid = p.id
GROUP BY p.id, p.[date], p.name
```